# CSS getting duplicated in DOM

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

I facing an issue where my CSS is getting duplicated when showing up in the DOM tree. Its a React JS application.

Its happening across all divs

I tried clearing cache, npm install.

If rename one CSS then it works fine for that only but the problem still remains.

[image]

I have a login.js file and login.css file. Below snippet is from login.css

```
.btn-login {
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 10px;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.9;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }

.btn-login:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please include more of your code - i.e where you are defining these styles, the component you are in, and how you are outputting the styles.

Comment: added. U see, there only one css. I am not understanding why its being duplicated. Also, in the DOM tree if i uncheck rules from top the bottom one takes effect

Comment: Are you importing this css file twice, in different files maybe?

Comment: no. just once i have imported.

Comment: previously i had background-color, then i removed it. it does not reflect. my updated css shows below it with a strikethrough. idk what is happening.

Comment: it happens on internet explorer and chrome.

Comment: You really need to add the rest of your code -- it is literally impossible to discern what is happening just looking at a lump of CSS...

Comment: I think need your full CSS, too see where CSS style is getting duplicate

Comment: If you have a close look, then your style is coming from `<style>` element of HTML not any other `CSS` file.

Comment: but the problem is not related only to login. It is across the app. this is just a part of the code i have put from login. The issue seems to be related to configuration rather than code. If anyone has encountered something like this then please help

Comment: Seriously - you need to post a lot more code than just the CSS part - we cannot possibly help based on what information is here :/

Comment: Did you ever solve this? This is happening to me as well. Bizarrely, only in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @BitShift, I had to re-create the project and drag and drop files manually into the new project. After that issue did not come, but there is a chance it might.